# Collaborative sessions with ARFaceAnchor and ARBodyAnchor

Tags: arkit, realitykit

I have set up an ARKit collaborative session, using a custom Network Framing Protocol, which successfully exchanges collaborative data between users. `ARParticipantAnchor` works as expected and I can successfully present a fully tracked Entity on that Anchor.

I tried to do the same with a `ARFaceAnchor`, however, Entities placed on `ARFaceAnchor`s don't seem to be exchanged over the network with the other participants. I am also planning to try to do the same with a `ARBodyAnchor`.

Has anybody tried to work with `ARFaceAnchor`s or `ARBodyAnchor`s on a collaborative ARKit/RealityKit session?

Have you found any kind of documentation mentioning potential restrictions on the type of Entities or Anchors exchanged during a collaborative session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### ARBodyTrackingConfiguration

Since all RealityKit configurations are based on ARKit configs, we'll discuss the latter. To exchange data in a multiuser session, at least two things are needed - a point cloud (a.k.a. ARWorldMap –  to understand where surrounding world objects are) and an ability to collaborate with other parties.

Although `ARBodyTrackingConfig` ***does have*** the [initialWorldMap](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2968180-initialworldmap) instance property (explicitly indicating that we are able to work with its environmental sparse point cloud), this configuration lacks the [isCollaborationEnabled](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/3152987-iscollaborationenabled) flag. `ARFaceTrackingConfig` ***doesn't have*** both properties.

[image]

[image]

[image]

By default, `initialWorldMap = nil` and `isCollaborationEnabled = false`.